# Compiling node.js, as means of testing for runtime errors?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to compile a node.js program as a way of discovering 'evident' errors, rather than waiting for runtime. Currently I use eslint and testing, but would be I interested to see if there are other tools that can help reduce the risk?

I come from a background of Java development, where I am used to the compiler catching some of these mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compile as such, but you can use a linter instead.

jshint is one of several available.
[jshint documentation page](http://jshint.com/docs/)

The idea is to check the code for mistakes and errors, similar to the checks a compiler would make.

This process won't find all types of runtime errors but it will discover many of the issue that would be found by the compiler in languages like Java.